# Chrome not working on amazon.com?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm running Chrome Version 48.0.2564.116 (64-bit) on OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite) on a high-powered Macbook Pro (16G RAM, etc.).

When I visit any product detail page on amazon.com, it doesn't load some of the components (e.g., Q&A, product reviews) and instead spins forever.  Looking at "Activity Monitor" it is 100% CPU and won't stop until I kill the tab.  I turned off all my extensions, same behavior.

I'm using Firefox, which is fine.  Just wondered if there's an easy fix for Chrome.